# How do video encoding standards(like h.264) then serialize motion prediction?

Tags: encoding, h.264, codec, motion-detection, x264

Motion prediction brute force algorithms, in a nutshell work like this(if I'm not mistaken):

1. Search every possible macroblock in the search window
2. Compare each of them with the reference macroblock
3. Take the one that is the most similar and encode the DIFFERENCE between the frames instead of the actual frame.

Now this in theory makes sense to me. But when it gets to the actual serializing I'm lost. We've found the most similar block. We know where it is, and from that we can calculate the distance vector of it. Let's say it's about 64 pixels to the right.

Basically, when serializing this block, we do:

- Ignore everything but luminosity(encode only Y, i think i saw this somewhere?), take note of the difference between it and the reference block
- Encode the motion, a distance vector
- Encode the MSE, so we can reconstruct it

Is the output of this a simple 2D array of luminosity values, with an appended/prepended MSE value and distance vector? Where is the compression in this? We got to take out the UV component? There seem to be many resources that take on the surface level of video encoders, but it's very hard to find actual in-depth explanations of modern video encoders. Feel free to correct me on my above statements.

Comment: Its pretty complicated to explain in a SO post. At the impressive level of understanding you seem to already have, you should probably just read the standard. Search for "14496-10" and it should be pretty easy to find a pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Grossly oversimplified:

Encoders include built-in decoder functionality. That generates a reference frame for the encoder to use. It's the same frame, inaccuracies and all, that comes out of the decoder at the far end for display to the viewer.

Motion estimation, which can be absent, simple, or complex, generates a motion vector for each 4x4 or 16x16 macroblock, by comparing the reference frame to the input frame.

The decoders (both the built-in one and the one at the far end) apply them to their current decoded image.

Then the encoder generates the pixel-by-pixel differences between the input image and decoded image, compresses them, and sends them to to the decoder. H.264 first uses lossy integer transforms (a form of discrete cosine transforms) on the luma and chroma channels. Then it applies lossless entropy coding to the output of the integer transforms. ("zip" and "gzip" are examples of lossless entropy coding, but not the codings used in H.264).

The point of motion estimation is to reduce the differences between the input image and the reference image before encoding those differences.

(This is for P frames. It's more complex for B frames.)

Dog-simple motion estimation could compute a single overall vector and apply it to all macroblocks in the image. That would be useful for applications where the primary source of motion is slowly panning and tilting the camera.

More complex motion estimation can be optimized for one or more talking heads. Another way to handle it would be to detect multiple arbitrary objects and track each object's movement from frame to frame.

And, if an encoder cannot generate motion vectors at all, everything works the same on the decoder.

The complexity of motion estimation is a feature of the encoder. The more compute cycles it can use to search for motion, the fewer image differences there will be from frame to frame, and so the fewer image-difference bits need to be sent to the far end for the same image-difference quantization level.  So, the viewer gets better picture quality for the same number of bits per second, or alternatively the same picture quality for fewer bits per second.

Motion estimation can analyze the luma only, or the luma and chroma. The motion vectors are applied to the luma and both chroma channels in all cases.

Comment: " Then the encoder generates the pixel-by-pixel differences between the input image and decoded image, compresses them, and sends them to to the decoder.

"
How are the differences serialized? You've got a YUV pixel 1 and YUV pixel 2, is the difference between them not the same amount of bits in terms of capacity? It's still a YUV difference between them is it not?

Comment: A large topic. Search for "how does H.264 work" and read about it on the intertoobz.

Comment: Well my "intertoobz" adventure hasn't been very successful when looking for the specific question. They all mention that the difference is encoded, but now how it's encoded, which is a giant roadblock in my development right now.

Comment: See my edit for a summary. Here's a basic reference. https://www.vcodex.com/an-overview-of-h264-advanced-video-coding/

Comment: I've read through that before. It says "subtract prediction from current macroblock". How is subtracting compressing anything when serializing? If i'm using 256 bits per each pixel, and the difference is 40 pixels, am i going to variable length encode this difference? It doesn't say, which is why I'm looking for something not as surface level.